# Apostrophe’s are not searchable with server side datatable individual column search

Tags: laravel, datatable, server-side

I am using a server-side data table with laravel and I am trying to search Apostrophe’s value (Fran'k) but it's not working with individual column search. Please help me

I am using below code for column search

```
$('input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
     if (tables.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
           tables
              .column(i)
              .search(this.value )
              .draw();
     }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You should provide the code to help debufg

Comment: Please check edited question @DevinGray

Comment: It is a laravel serverside problem, you must identify where the backend code perform the search and fix whatever the problem is.